# How to return a Promise from a function passed to Deferred.pipe()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

The following chain is to be executed sequentially

```
   $.when()
       .pipe(functionA)
       .pipe(functionB)
       .fail(functionC);
```

where `functionA` returns a Promise.

```
function functionA() {
  return networkCall().then(sideEffectsForSuccess).catch(sideEffectsForFailure);
}

function networkCall() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return $.ajax(...);
  });
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, since `functionB` gets immediately executed without waiting for the Promise returned from functionA to resolve (or fail). The chain works correctly if `functionA` is changed to

```
function functionA() {
  return $.ajax(...).pipe(sideEffectsForSuccess, sideEffectsForFailure);
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to use `networkCall`. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I actually don't know a lot about jquery's when/pipe etc BUT it's 2022, you really should use native promises - they're supported by almost every browser since some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you return the promise

```
function functionA() {
   let callPromise = networkCall();
   callPromise.then(sideEffectsForSuccess).catch(sideEffectsForFailure);
   return callPromise;
}
```